# Connect SFTP using no port?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, putty, filezilla

I want to connect to an ubuntu server from windows. I have information to the host's ip address, username, and the private key, but no port information provided. How to connect the SFTP without defining the port number?

Note: I have succesfully connect them using FileZilla but no luck with putty or winscp as I need to write terminal command.

[connection setting using FileZilla - succeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIzGt.png)

[connection setting using puTTY - failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EqIY.png)

[puTTY error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhH5c.png)

Comment: Use the default port number: 22 , however  - please post questions that are not programming related to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You must have a port number. SFTP defaults to 22 since it is FTP over SSH, however the host may be expecting connections from another port. Without knowing which port to use, you will be unable to connect.

Comment: But why it is succesful to connect via filezilla without using port number?

Comment: Filezilla uses 22 as the default port. For putty you have to provide 22 as the port number.

Comment: Correct. Though 1) SFTP is not FTP over SSH. 2) The question is off-topic.